# Hide/show ImageView dynamically in getView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Im trying to check if a directory exists, and if it does I want to make an imageview in a listview visible. For some reason the imageview is not being set visible even when the directory exists. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater(); 
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);


    String item = data.get(position);
    ImageView ib = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.alreadyDownloaded);
    TextView textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.fontTextView);
    textView.setText(data.get(position));

    File dfDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DownloadedFonts"+ (data.get(position)));

    if(dfDir.isDirectory()) {
  //if (item.equals("Helvetica") ){ if i use this it hides the image properly
        ib.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }    

    return row;

}
```

Comment: Is it actually entering the `if` block?

Comment: The code assumes your imageView visibility is initialized to INVISIBLE or GONE inside your xml layout file. Is that true ?

Comment: Does `ImageView` initially visible?

Comment: I believe so, because if I change the selection statement to the one that I commented out, it works fine.

Comment: Ive set this to the imageview in the xml: `android:visibility="invisible"`

Comment: I think if-block doesn't executes.

Comment: "My code is not working." Fairly useless statement. Better tell us what you expected, what you got, does it crash (StackTrace?)...anything concrete? We'd not need to ask ten other question to know what's going on.

Comment: maybe the folder is wrong? try this ->

File dfDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DownloadedFonts/"+ (data.get(position)));